# is there a way to open ICMP on an Azure Pipeline vm?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, ping

is there a way to open ICMP on an Azure Pipeline vm? my CI unit tests are expected to send ping requests to the google DNS (8.8.8.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you are trying to access one external IP through Azure VM endpoint with Ping. **This does not allowed**.

Please due to this official blog which written by our Azure VM team engineer: [HOW TO ALLOW PING FUNCTIONALITY TO WINDOWS AZURE MACHINES?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_guide/2014/12/13/how-to-allow-ping-functionality-to-windows-azure-machines/)

> The Ping functionality on Windows Azure VM is blocked by default for
>   security reasons.

As we all know, the **ICMP** protocol which used by Ping can measure the latency of the connection between a local machine and a remote machine. Any connections exceeding a default latency are deemed to be unavailable. See the pic shown below, the only possible connection to that Azure virtual machine is via the **Internet**. Any internet traffic which trying to enter the virtual network must pass through the **load balancer**, and this balancer **is filtering ICMP traffic**, allow **UDP** and **TCP** traffic.

> By default, Azure denies and blocks all public inbound traffic to an
>   Azure virtual machine,   includes ICMP traffic. This is a good thing
>   because it can improve security by reducing the attack surface.

[image]

**Note:** This restrict only apply to the network traffic which going through the external IP through configured endpoints. But if the network traffic occurred between internal IPs of VMs which in the same virtual network or in the same cloud service, ICMP would be allowed.

This restrict does not limited permanently. We can set **firefall** or **[azure security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview?WT.mc_id=thomasmaurer-blog-thmaure)** to allow this. But, unfortunately, for Azure Devops Pipeline, the hosted agent is using the VM `DS2_V2` and `DS3_V2`, which are all could not be configured\modified with firefall and security group by external users. If build\release with **private agent**, ICMP will not be limit. You can set a **private agent**, and execute ping test in it.

*(Sometimes, can use **VPN** or **ExpressRoute** to skip the load balancer filter and limit. But I don't recommend to use this way)*

---

Since Ping is a very convenient and critical tool for troubleshooting connectivity, we are reviewing and considering to expand this feature in Azure VM. There has a such suggestion ticket raised in our uservoice forum: [Enable ICMP traffic to Azure VMs over the Internet](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/6423260-enable-icmp-traffic-to-azure-vms-over-the-internet). You can vote for it as well to push it faster into the development queue.

Comment: "Enable ICMP traffic to Azure VMs over the Internet" link is not reachable.